# Populate TreeView From Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, treeview

I saw this question many times but funny enough I didn't understand any answer given (and it seems like people who asked this question didn't understand the answer either because they didn't accept any answer).

I have a to-do list and in an entity of a to-do, you can have another to-do with no limit, you can have 100 layers of parents.

My way of solving this is that in my database (using EF6), I have an `int` column  (which is called `parent`) that represents the ID of a parent which can be null in case it's the first level (has no parent).

I want to populate that into a TreeView in a WPF application - what would be the shortest and simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> what would be the shortest and simplest way to do that?

[Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#lazy-loading).

The alternatives are

1. Eager Loading *all* ToDo entities.
2. Loading with a Raw SQL query that implements the recursive logic.  EG in SQL Server a Recursive CTE.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain well... I know how to query it, What I need to know is how can I populate it in TreeView in a way that it knows which one is a child to what Entity and organize it